# Host blazor webassembly in Jelastic cloud

Tags: blazor, webassembly, jelastic

Is it possible to tweak Jelastic's .NET Core application server to build and launch blazor webassembly?
Basically instead of `dotnet run` I need to execute something like

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release
dotnet run --configuration Release --project Server
```

Comment: This functionality is planned to be delivered soon, but no ETA so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For publishing, the post-deploy hook should be used

```
cd $WEBROOT && dotnet publish --configuration Release
```

For running, these variables should be set

```
APP_NAME=Server
RUN_OPTION= --configuration Release
```

Comment: I did that to .net 6 Node by setting the variables in the environment variables 
but no use
btw my project is uploaded to repo (Github)